# array is not mapping in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I keep getting this error while I have tried everything according to my knowledge any kind of help will be appreciated.

I try to pass the array in props then get in component and set props value in the state but when I try to map that array this error shows up:

```sh
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

onClick function:

```js
const handleClickOpen = (data) => {
  setOpen(true);
  setPropsData(data);
};
```

Event handler:

```js
onClick={() => {
  handleClickOpen({
    name: item.firstName,
    image: item.image,
    about: item.about,
    id: item._id,
    interests: item.intersets,
  });
}}
```

Component passing props:

```js
<ProfileDialog
  selectedValue={propsData}
  open={open}
  onClose={handleClose}
/>
```

Component declares props like so:

```js
const { onClose, selectedValue, interests, open } = props;
```

I got the error when I put in this statement:

```
<div>{selectedValue.interests.map((item,i) => console.log(item,i))}</div>
```

Comment: Try this `<div>{selectedValue?.interests.map((item,i) => console.log(item,i))}</div>`

Comment: I can't tell much with that much code example. You might want to verify if selectedValue.interests is an array. Try logging them first.

Comment: wait I just try but I don't know how to share code on the sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you set the value `interests` are undefined. do null check before access.

```
selectedValue?.interests?.map
```

It is recommended to do `null` check before accessing nested objects, [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) will help us in this regard.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out/adding documentation for optional chaining so your answer is more clear.